# How do I make wp_get_archives show me months where only pages were created?

Tags: archives

I am creating a plugin and have a problem,

this code gives my all months that post were added:

```
        <select name="sdate" id="sdate">
    <?php wp_get_archives('format=option'); ?>
        </select>
```

the problem is that i dont get dates that only pages were added.

basicaly, i want dropdown thats gonna list every year+month (for example "September 2010") that something was added with value like "year-month" (for example "2010-05")

Something that you can see working on Wordpress Export page, but copied code is not working for me.

Comment: Sounds like wp_get_archives only works for posts, but not pages!

Comment: I would love to know how to get wp_get_archives to work for pages.

Answer (score 5):

The wp_get_archives() function runs a filter on its WHERE clause--it's called **getarchives_where**. You could use this to modify the query to only include pages rather than posts (which is the hard-coded default).

I haven't tested this yet, but try it out:

```
add_filter('getarchives_where','my_archives_filter');

function my_archives_filter($where_clause) {

  return "WHERE post_type = 'page' AND post_status = 'publish'";

}
```

Then, just use the wp_get_archives function the way you normally would.

Obviously, this will affect the wp_get_archives function sitewide, so if you use wp_get_archives for grabbing a post archive somewhere else on your site, you'll have to wrap the add_filter in something that recognizes the context.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is code that make it all work(display archive dropdown list with dates that anything has been added):

```
    add_filter('getarchives_where','my_archives_filter');

    function my_archives_filter($where_clause='') {
        return "";
    }


        <select name="sdate" id="sdate">
               <?php wp_get_archives('format=option'); ?>
        </select>
```

Thanks MathSmath!